# mocking/stubbing a function that returns another function

Tags: node.js, mocking, mocha.js, sinon, body-parser

I have two functions `funcA` and `funcB`

`funcA` is being an npm module, and `funcB` is custom function that calls `funcA`

`funcB.js`:

```
const a = require('a')
const funcB = ()=> a.funcA({arg})
```

I want to test that a.funcA has been called when invoking funcB

`funcB.test.js`:

```js
describe("", () => {
  it("should call a.funcA", () => {
    sandbox.stub(a, "funcA");
    funcB();
    expect(a.funcA).to.have.been.called;
  });
});
```

`funcA`:

```js
function funcA() {
  //....
  return function c() {
    //other logic here.
  };
}
```

When i run test, i get this message: 
I got `a.funcA` is not a spy or a call to a spy! error

How do i stub `funcA`? any ideas? ive tried mockquire but wouldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`funcB.js`:

```js
const a = require("./a");
const funcB = () => a.funcA({ arg: 123 });
exports.funcB = funcB;
```

`a.js`:

```js
exports.funcA = function funcA(args) {
  return function c() {};
};
```

`funcB.test.js`:

```js
const { expect } = require("chai");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const a = require("./a");
const { funcB } = require("./funcB");

describe("57796168", () => {
  let sandbox;
  before(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });
  it("should call a.funcA", () => {
    const funcAStub = sandbox.stub(a, "funcA");
    funcB();
    sinon.assert.calledWith(funcAStub, { arg: 123 });
    expect(funcAStub.callCount).to.be.equal(1);
    expect(funcAStub.calledWith({ arg: 123 })).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```js
 57796168
    ✓ should call a.funcA


  1 passing (10ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |    94.74 |      100 |    66.67 |    94.44 |                   |
 a.js          |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |                 2 |
 funcB.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 funcB.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57796168